# Why can't CASE be used on string values and only symbol values?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, land-of-lisp

In book 'land of lisp' I read

> Because the case command uses eq for comparisons, it is usually used
>   only for branching on symbol values. It cannot be used to branch on
>   string values, among other things.

Please explain why?

Comment: Additional hint: there are other `case`-like constructs in the library `alexandria`, including such that can compare strings.

Comment: Because a string is like a list of characters. Only way to compare two strings that are not eq is to check if all the parts are eql. Case works with symbols, numbers and characters since they are primitive values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The other two excellent answers do answer the question asked. I will try to answer the natural next question - why does [`case`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_case_.htm) use [`eql`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eql.htm)?

The reason is actually the same as in `C` (where the corresponding `switch` statement uses numeric comparison): the `case` forms in Lisp are usually compiled to something like `goto`, so `(case x (1 ...) (2 ...) (3 ...))` is much more efficient than the corresponding [`cond`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_cond.htm). This is often accomplished by compiling `case` to a hash table lookup which maps the value being compared to the clause directly.

That said, the next question would be - why not have a `case` variant with `equal` hash table clause lookup instead of `eql`? Well, this is not in the ANSI standard, but implementations can provide such extensions, e.g., [`ext:fcase`](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/fcase.html) in CLISP.

See also [why `eql` is the default comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19296172/850781).

Answer (score 10):

Two strings with the same content "foo" and "foo" are not EQL. `CASE` uses `EQL` as a comparison (not `EQ` as in your question). Usually one might want different tests: string comparison case and case insensitive, for example. But for `CASE` on cannot use another test. `EQL` is built-in. `EQL` compares for pointer equality, numbers and characters. But not string contents. You can test if two strings are the identical data objects, though.

So, two strings `"FOO"` and `"FOO"` are usually two different objects.

But two symbols `FOO` and `FOO` are usually really the same object. That's a basic feature of Lisp. Thus they are `EQL` and `CASE` can be used to compare them.

Answer (score 5):

Because `(eq "foo" "foo")` is not necessarily true. Each time you type a string literal, it may create a fresh, unique string. So when `CASE` is comparing the value with the literals in the cases with `EQ`, they won't match.

Comment: This isn't entirely true;  the compiler could merge the two constants in compiled system, and `(eq "foo" "foo")` could be true.  You're right, of course, that there's no _guarantee_ that `(eq "foo" "foo")` is true.  "`(eq "Foo" "Foo")`
=>  true
OR=>  false" is even one of the examples in the [hyperspec entry on `eq`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq.htm).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I've added qualifiers to my answer.