# Test if array is inside a list in lisp

Tags: arrays, list, find, common-lisp, clisp

I have two items.  The first, `a-child`, is a list which contains an array as its first element and then some strings as the remaining elements.  The other, `mapped`, is a list which contains a number of arrays.  By inspection, it's easy to see that `a-child` is in `mapped`, though I can't find a function which will find it for me.

I apologize for the poor lisp style below - I started a few days ago, so I haven't picked up all the conventions yet.

```
(defparameter a-child (list (#2A((1 2 3) (7 4 5) (9 8 6))) "U" "R" "R"))
(defparameter mapped (list (#2A((1 2 3) (7 4 5) (9 8 6))) (#2A((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)))))
(find (car a-child) mapped)   ;;returns NIL
(member (car a-child) mapped) ;;returns NIL
(position (car a-child) mapped) ;;returns NIL
(equalp (car a-child) (car mapped)) ;;returns T
```

What function can I use to look for arrays within a list of arrays??  Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## The Answer

Your sequence functions marked "returns NIL" will return `T` if you pass `:test #'equalp` to them.

## The Reason

The default [Two-Argument Test](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_ba.htm) in Common Lisp is [`eql`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eql.htm).

It is the most reasonable choice between the 4(!) general purpose comparison functions provided for by the ANSI CL standard:

- [`eq`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq.htm) is too implementation-dependent and does not work as one probably wants on numbers and characters
- [`equal`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_equal.htm) and [`equalp`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_equalp.htm) traverse objects and thus take long time for huge ones and may never terminate for circular ones.

See also [the difference between eq, eql, equal, and equalp in Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547436/whats-the-difference-between-eq-eql-equal-and-equalp-in-common-lisp).

Comment: In most newer scripting languages, something akin to CL's `equal` is the ordinary comparison operator. Notably, it works intuitively on strings and vectors. It may be that the possibility of making circular lists in Lisp is the reason why `equal` was not chosen as the default. `equal` doesn't need to be slower than `eql` when comparing different types, as it only needs to traverse the data structure if all its arguments are of the same type.