# Can find be used to find a list in another list?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Finding list elements based on single atoms seems to work fine:

```
CL-USER> (find 1 (list 5 4 3 2 1))
1
```

But what about finding a list in a list?

```
CL-USER> (find (list 1 2) (list (list 3 4) (list 1 2)))
NIL
```

How to do it?

Comment: Try `(find (list 1 2) (list (list 3 4) (list 1 2)))`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if array is inside a list in lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287777/test-if-array-is-inside-a-list-in-lisp); especially the explanation of the choice of the default `:test` predicate in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FIND` by default uses `EQL` for testing for an element. This test however for lists returns true only if the two objects are the same (i.e. if they are `EQ`) and not if they have equal elements.

Thus:

```
(find (list 1 2) (list (list 1 2) (list 1 2 3))) ==> NIL

(let ((L1 (list 1 2))
      (L2 (list 1 2 3)))
  (find L1 (list L1 L2))) ==> (1 2)
```

but you can also specify a different test function

```
(find (list 1 2) (list (list 1 2) (list 1 2 3))
      :test #'EQUAL) ==> (1 2)
```