# Understanding data mode in Lisp, why are these expressions not the same?

Tags: common-lisp, equality, land-of-lisp

Currently I am reading "Land of Lisp". In one of the recent code samples the author gave:

```
> (eq 'fooo 'FoOo)
T
```

to prove that the symbols are case-insensitive. A few pages later *data mode* is formally introduced.

However I fail to *really* understand the following. `eq` is a function, so its name is case-insensitive as well. Therefore I should be able to do this:

```
> (eq 'Eq 'EQ)
T
```

Great. That worked as expected. But what if I put this into a list in data mode? Keep in mind, I am just experimenting with something that's new for me.

```
> (eq '(Eq) '(EQ))
NIL
> (eq '('Eq) '('EQ))
NIL
```

Uhm. Okay? Why is that? I would have expected that if I put the same symbol into two lists, that the lists would be considered equal.

Now the question: does that mean that not the contents of the lists are compared, but the list "objects" themselves? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Symbols are Case-Sensitive

```
> (eq (print (intern "foo")) (print (intern "FOO")))
|foo|   ; printed 
FOO     ; printed
==> NIL ; returned
```

## The default reader is Case-Converting

```
(eq (read-from-string "foo") (read-from-string "FOO"))
==> T
```

However, you can make the reader case-preserving:

```
(let ((*readtable* (copy-readtable)))
  (setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :preserve)
  (eq (read-from-string "foo") (read-from-string "FOO")))
==> NIL
```

Please take a look at

- [Reader Algorithm](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_b.htm)
- [Effect of Readtable Case on the Lisp Reader](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/23_ab.htm)

## EQ compares for pointer identity

[Common Lisp provides **4** equality predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287777/test-if-array-is-inside-a-list-in-lisp/19296172#19296172), you should use the right one for your needs:

```
(equal '(Eq) '(EQ))
==> T
(equal '('Eq) '('EQ))
==> T
```

Comment: Ouch, I get the feeling I haven't peeked behind the surface a lot. Thanks for the detailed help!

Answer (score 2):

`eq` compares for things to be *exactly the same*, think pointer equality. This is like `==` in Java, even logically equivalent data will be falsy.

The solution here is to use `equal` which just does the "intelligent" thing and compares the lists' elements

```
> (equal '(A) '(a))
T
```

Additionally symbols are case sensitive. But by default the reader (the thing that turns code into an AST) defaults to being case insensitive. You can notice this distinction with a function like `intern`.

Answer (score 1):

Lisp symbols are case sensitive. And even the lisp reader is case sensitive. The only point is that when the reader reads a symbol it usually make it in uppercase. The easiest way to tell the reader that the case in important is to put it between the vertical lines.

```
> '|asd|def|ghj|
|asdDEFght|
> '|asd|
|asd|
> '|ASD|
ASD
> 'ASD
ASD
> (eq 'asd '|ASD|)
t
> (eq 'asd '|aSd|)
nil
```

The `eq` predicate check that the arguments are the same objects (similar to compare the pointers to variables in `C`)

```
> (defparameter *x* 1)
> (defparameter *y* 1)
> (eq *x* *y*)
nil
```

So when you write `'(asd)` in `REPL` the list with one element is created. And when you write it the second time another list is created and these lists are actually different objects.

```
> (defparameter *list1* '('qwe))
> (defparameter *list2* '('qwe))
> (eq *list1* list2*) ;this are 2 different objects
nil
> (setf (first *list1* 'def))
> *list1* ;this list has changed
(DEF)
> *list2* ;and this did not
(QWE)

> (setf *list1* *list2*) ;now they are just different names for one object
> *list1*
(QWE)
> (eq *list1* *list2*)
t
```

There are another ways how to compare objects (`eq` `eql` `equal` `equalp` `=`). It's better to read documentation and play with `REPL` to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

To complicate things a bit.

Let's say we have the following in a file. Then we compile and load that file.

```
(defparameter *a* '(1))
(defparameter *b* '(1))
```

Now we calculate:

```
(eq *a* *b*)
```

It is undefined if this is `NIL` or `T`. The Common Lisp compiler *may* detect that the lists are `equal` and set both variables to the same list - that is `EQ` then also would be true. Actually there are Common Lisp compilers which are doing this. Executing the two `DEFPARAMETER` forms in a *REPL`one would usually expect that the Lisp system does not detect that and that`(eq *a* *b*)`is`NIL`.

`EQUAL` compares structure and `(eq *a* *b*)` for our example is always `T`.