# LISP function substitute does not substitute my string

Tags: lisp

I am trying to understand the function "substitute" in LISP, but there is something that I don't understand.
When I perform this:

```lisp
(defparameter *mytree* nil)
(push 1 *mytree*)
(substitute '8 '1 *mytree*)
```

Everything runs ok, the value of *mytree* is (8).

But, when I perform:

```lisp
(defparameter *mytree* nil)
(push "A" *mytree*)
(substitute '8 '"A" *mytree*)
```

Then *mytree* is ("A") instead of (8) like I expect.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is this actually a problem? You're getting `(8)` the first time because it substituted `'8` for `'1`. The second time, it substitutes `'8` for `'"A"`, so you're still getting the right answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if array is inside a list in lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287777/test-if-array-is-inside-a-list-in-lisp)

Comment: I didn't get the same result on the second example.

Comment: @matthew, sorry I made a mistake. I change it.

Comment: @mbratch, substitution rely on eql to find the item to replace. and eql can behave differently, but as said by Jordon on sbcl implementation (eql "A" "A") return nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the correct equality checking method by using the :test keyword in substitute.

The signature for `substitute` is

`(substitute newitem olditem sequence &key from-end test test-not start end count key)`

`Substitute` is using `eql` by default, but that won't work in this scenario

```
(eql "A" "A") ;; nil
(equal "A" "A") ;; t
```

This will yield the correct results

```
(defparameter *mytree* nil)
(push "A" *mytree*)
(substitute 8 "A" *mytree* :test 'equal) ;; note the test, returns (8)
```