# Why are there so many ways to compare for equality?

Tags: comparison, lisp, common-lisp, equality

If I want to compare two values for equality there are a number of options, such as:

- `eq` for symbols
- `=` for numbers
- `char-equal` for characters
- `string-equal` for strings
- `eql` for symbols, numbers and strings
- `equal` for everything but symbols
- …

(And I hope I got this right so far.)

Now, as a Lisp beginner, my question is: Why is that? Is this just for "historical reasons" or is there a real benefit of having all these possibilities?

I know that *why*-questions are always hard to answer and may be opinion-based, but I think (guess) that there are best practices that are commonly agreed on by advanced Lisp developers.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287777/test-if-array-is-inside-a-list-in-lisp/19296172#19296172) about the 4 general comparison functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually can compare everything with `eq`, `eql`, `equal` and `equalp`. But choose for yourself, what's needed:

It's easy to think that `eq` compare pointers. Thus symbols (because a unique symbol enters package only once and its address is the same in every case you use it) will return true.

```
CL-USER> (eq 'a 'a)
T
```

Next, different lists, even if contain the same values, are not equal (in terms of `eq`). They have different addresses, they are different objects.

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *a* '(1 2))
*A*
CL-USER> (defparameter *b* '(1 2))
*B*
CL-USER> (eq *a* *b*)
NIL
```

But it's not always true, for example if you're dealing with literal object:

```
CL-USER> (lambda nil '(1 2 3))
#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA NIL '(1 2 3)>
CL-USER> (eq * *)
T
```

While:

```
CL-USER> (eq '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3))
NIL
```

Tricky? You may expect that values of different variables that contain the same numbers will not be equal, since the numbers should occupy different blocks of memory, but...

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *c* 5)
*C*
CL-USER> (defparameter *d* 5)
*D*
CL-USER> (eq *c* *d*)
T
```

Description of `eq` function says about identical objects, so number five is the same object everywhere.

Next, `eql` function is defined upon `eq`, it evaluates `t` in the following cases:

- If x and y are `eq`.
- If x and y are both numbers of the same type and the same value.
- If they are both characters that represent the same character.

And `equal`, `equalp` deal with 'visually similar' objects.

Why so many of them? Think for yourself: in language like LISP where you do not work with pointers explicitly you may want to find exactly the same object (at the same address) in list or anywhere.. So you need function that acts on this 'pointer' level. Next it's obvious that you need 'normal' comparison functions and here they are. Differences are subtle and somewhat historic, but it's often useful to have them all.

It's also important to note that some of these 4 base comparison functions have additional meaning being applied to certain types of data. For example `equal` works for comparison of strings in case-sensitive manner, while `equalp` in case-insensitive one.

```
CL-USER> (equal "My String" "My String")
T
CL-USER> (equal "My String" "My string")
NIL
CL-USER> (equalp "My String" "My string")
T
```

To continue with the string example, here are many functions like `string=`, etc. Why? That's what 'The Common Lisp Cookbook' says:

> You'll want to use these if you're deploying *implementation-defined* attributes of characters. Check your vendor's documentation in this case.

However, in vast majority of cases the 4 basic functions will be enough.

Comment: In most lisps, small (fixnum) numbers will compare equal using `EQ` because the fixnum representation is essentially a pointer tagged as "this is a fixnum". But in mosts lisps, things like `(eq (ash 1 128) (ash 1 128))` will return false (until 128+ bit fixnums become common, at least).

Answer (score 5):

There are so many because there are specialized comparison functions that are optimized for certain types. Using them might give you better performance.

This simple rule I read in [Land of Lisp](http://landoflisp.com/)

- Use `eq` to compare identify the same object (pointer equal)
- Use `equal` for everything that looks the same

Now sometimes you want to test if a string is equal case insensitively and then `equal` wouldn't do that since "test" and "TEST" don't look the same. `string-equal` would be the right choice.

When comparing different types of number, like 3.0 and 3 they don't look the same. However if you do `(= 3 3.0)` it's `T` since they represent the same value if the fixnum was casted down to a float.

Also `equalp` is like `equal` except it does string case insensitive and numbers like `=`. I'm not entirely sure but in my mind a third rule would be:

- Use `equalp` for everything that means the same

So you'll come pretty far with just those 3 generic ones but some cases you might need to search [CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Front/index.htm) for a specialized equality operator.

Comment: [here](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equalp.htm) is definition of `equalp`, so I guess I looks for type of arguments and calls corresponding function, like `=` or `char-equal`, so you're right,  basic function must be more efficient.

Comment: I **<3** the idea of the third rule: *Use `equalp` when you want to compare whether things mean the same.*

Answer (score 3):

There are basically two sets of comparisons:

- general purpose: EQ (pointer), EQL (pointer + number + char), EQUAL, EQUALP
- type specific: string-equal, string=, ...

The general purpose comparisons try to provide functionality for basic use cases in typical (mostly) symbolic programming.

The type specific comparisons are thought to express (and possibly check) that the arguments are of some type. They also provide efficient implementations. They were added so that these functions can be used in code, which needs to expand into or call specific and efficient functions.