# Equality predicates for hash tables

Tags: comparison, lisp, hashtable, common-lisp, predicate

As a result of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032028/why-are-there-so-many-ways-to-compare-for-equality) investigation, we know that using special functions (optimized for certain types of data) is a good idea. I would like to create a hash table, but [this source](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_mk_has.htm) says:

> **Syntax:**
>
> make-hash-table &key test size rehash-size rehash-threshold => hash-table
>
> **Arguments and Values:**
>
> test - a designator for one of the functions *eq*, *eql*, *equal*, or *equalp*. The default is *eql*.

Well, well. What if I wanna speed up my program when I work with strings and use `string-equal` for instance? There is no restrictions regarding equality predicates for other high-order functions, but for `make-hash-table` they are. What is the reason of that?

Bonus "history-of-lisp" question: why the function `gethash` is named so? Why not `get-hash`?

Comment: Bonus-answer: In [naming convensions](http://www.cliki.net/Naming+conventions) it hints that it migth depend on what comes after `get`. If it's a hyphenated value you hyphenate like in `get-setf-method` but not if there is only one word like `gethash`. CL is a join of several already existing LISPs so it's not strange the naming convention looks a little bumpy and some of CL looks like it's designed by different designers :-p

Comment: That's actually consistent with the rule for appending `p` to predicates!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What is a Hash Table

A hash table works by computing a hash of an object and storing the object in a, well, table, indexed by the hash.
The test function must satisfy the fundamental condition that for all objects `x` and `y`:

```
(FUNCALL test-function x y) ⇒
(= (FUNCALL hash-function x) (FUNCALL hash-function y))
```

The ANSI CL standard specifies 4 standard test functions and, under the hood, implementations have the corresponding hash functions.

### Define Your Own Test/Hash

Some CL implementations allow you to define your own test-function/hash-function pairs, e.g.,

- [Macro `ext:define-hash-table-test`](http://clisp.org/impnotes/defhash.html)
- [Macro `sb-ext:define-hash-table-test`](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Hash-Table-Extensions)

### Your Specific Problem

When the table is string-keyed, I found it extremely profitable to use **symbols**.

I would create a special [package](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_pkg.htm) and [intern](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_intern.htm) my strings there.

Then I would [assign](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_5.htm) the value to the corresponding symbol: instead of

```
(defparameter *mytable* (make-hash-table :test 'equal))
(setf (gethash "foo" *mytable*) <whatever>)
```

I would do

```
(make-package "MY-PACKAGE")
(setf (symbol-value (intern "foo" "MY-PACKAGE")) <whatever>)
```

this is especially convenient when the strings are [read](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) because CL reader does interning for you.

There are some caveats, of course (e.g., packages have to be explicitly [deleted](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_del_pk.htm), otherwise they are not GCed), so this is probably not the the faint of heart.

Comment: Is defining of my own test/hash functions worth effort?

Comment: probably not. it really depends on _why_ you want to do that - and if performance is the goal, you need to make sure that this is the bottleneck first.