# How can I return values from a hash table in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, hashtable

I'm having trouble getting my hash table to reliably return values and I wonder whether someone might be able to advise?

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Make table:

`(setq table (make-hash-table))`

2. Define a variable for naming elements in the table, initial name is "bob" but in my program this will hold a user generated value, which will change from time to time:

`(defvar name-of-element "bob")`

3. Add a row to the table, named after the contents of `name-of-element`:

`(setf (gethash name-of-element table) "bob's element")`

4. When I retrieve the element from the table using the key `name-of-element`:

`(gethash name-of-element table)`

I get:

```
"bob's element"
T
```

5. But when I try to retrieve using `"bob"`:

`(gethash "bob" table)`

I get negative/no result:

```
N
N
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Please see [Equality predicates for hash tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24144210/850781) and [Why are there so many ways to compare for equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24032028/850781)

Comment: See also [Test if array is inside a list in lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19287777/850781).

Answer (score 4):

The default for the `:test` option to `make-hash-table` is `eql`. When you create a new string `"bob"`, it's not eql to the value of `name-of-element`, e.g.

```
(eql "bob" name-of-element) => NIL
```

Use `:test 'equal` to get a hash table that considers similar strings to be equivalent.

```
(defvar *table* (make-hash-table :test 'equal))
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the `:test 'equal` is an additional named argument to the `make-hash-table` constructor.