# Equivalent of LISP 'subst' function for LIST

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have the following list:

```
(1 (2))
```

And I want to subsitute (2) with (2 (3)) in order to obtain:

```
(1 (2 (3)))
```

The use of *subst* as followed does not return the wished result:

```
(subst '(2 (3)) '(2) '(1 (2)))
```

Is there a simple way to perform the substitution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if array is inside a list in lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287777/test-if-array-is-inside-a-list-in-lisp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default subst uses [eql](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_eql.htm), you must specify :test argument to use [#'equal](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_equal.htm), to get what you want.

```
CL-USER> (subst '(2 (3)) '(2)  '(1 (2)) :test #'equal)
(1 (2 (3)))
```

As you see, two directly specified lists aren't EQL, but they are EQUAL:

```
CL-USER> (eql '(2) '(2)) 
NIL
CL-USER> (equal '(2) '(2))
T
```

Read more [about eq, eql, equal and eqaulp difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547436/whats-the-difference-between-eq-eql-equal-and-equalp-in-common-lisp) in lisp.

Comment: It's also worth noting that **eql** isn't just **subst**'s default.  According to [17.2.1 Satisfying a Two-Argument Test](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_ba.htm), "If neither a **:test** nor a **:test-not** argument is supplied, it is as if a **:test** argument of **#'eql** was supplied."  That applies to the functions listed on that page (which includes **subst**).