# How to move an element in a list to the front of the list in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to check if a word is an element of a list.  It it isn't then add the word to the front of the list, but if it is move that word to the front of the list.  I am able to add the word to the list if it isn't already there, but I don't know how to the move the element to the front of the list if it is in the list already. Here is my code:

```
(defun movetofront (word lst)
  (cond
    ((member word lst) 
     (remove word lst))
    (T (cons word lst))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have to check for the presence:

```
(defun move-to-front (word list)
   (cons word (remove word list)))
```

Note that if `word` is, e.g., a `string`, [you will need to pass `:test`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19296172/850781) to [`remove`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_rm.htm).